# Apriori power: Mediated moderation with binary outcome

Tags: logistic, interaction, statistical-power, mediation

I would like to conduct an apriori power analysis to determine sample size on a moderated mediation model (x=continuous, mediator=continuous, moderator=binary, y=binary).  I use RStudio and SPSS and typically conduct power analyses using GPower.

I have not been able to find a paper that deals with both moderated mediation power analysis and logistic regressions.  I would greatly appreciate any advice (using R, GPower, or SPSS)or paper recomendations.